# Is there a way to "mask" an smtp server?

Tags: smtp

I am using a service for smtp relay and they give me a smtp server url (mail.theirdomain).. I wanted to ask if there is any way of "masking" this for example with some dns records to make the mail.theirdomain, mail.mydomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do a DNS lookup of `mail.theirdomain.com` and see what IP address this hostname points to (e.g. `x.x.x.x`).  Then, you can create a hostname `mail.mydomain.com`, and point this hostname to the same IP address (`x.x.x.x`).

But, if you do a reverse DNS lookup (i.e. PTR lookup) of `x.x.x.x`, it will likely point to `mail.theirdomain.com` (not `mail.mydomain.com`), and you can't change this, because you do not have control of `x.x.x.x`.

Also, if you open an SMTP connection to `mail.mydomain.com`, it will likely show `mail.theirdomain.com` in the SMTP banner that the server responds with after a client connects - and this is not something that you can change either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A tried pinging the mail.theirdomain.com and as it seems a different IP is shown for each location. Also, if they change one of their IP's, with my DNS records not changed it is not going to work.. is there another way?

Comment: This is starting to feel like an x-y problem.  What is the underlying thing that you are trying to accomplish with this 'masking'?  If you are trying to make `mail.theirdomain.com` appear as if it is in your domain, it may be possible to do so at first glance, but anyone with a bit of tech background can quickly 'unmask' this.

Comment: I'm making a project and I want to give to the customer the mail.mydomain.com and not the mail.theirdomain.com but still the traffic to be routed to the smtp servers from the smtp provider

Comment: wrt `A tried pinging the mail.theirdomain.com and as it seems a different IP is shown for each location` - they may be using DNS anycasting.  It's OK, as long as `mail.mydomain.com` points to any one of the IP addresses that `mai.theirdomain.com` points to.  wrt `Also, if they change one of their IP's, with my DNS records not changed it is not going to work` - yes, that's correct.  You may want to setup an automated job that checks this every few minutes, and updates `mail.mydomain.com` if necessary.

Comment: Oh ok I get it. I have one more question, isn't it going to break the ssl certificate? Or it is not needed?

Comment: That's a good point.  If the client connects using SSL (normally on port 465) or STARTSSL (normall on port 587 or port 25) then the client will get an SSL certificate error, because the common name in the certificate `mail.theirdomain.com` will not match the hostname that the client attempted to connect to `mail.yourdomain.com`.